# Server does not render ASP.NET Core web page and returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, ubuntu, hosting

The Ubuntu 22.04 server does not display the web page. It seems to be configured correctly.

There is a default file for nginx that redirects a specific port to the ASP.NET application:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 89.111.170.109;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Processes are running:
[processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDc1R.png)

Service is also running:
[service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCPqR.png)

There is a AspNetServer.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ASP .NET Web Application
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/netcore
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /var/www/netcore/WebApp.dll
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=netcore-demo
User=www-data
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Program.cs contains this code:

```
builder.Services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
{
    options.KnownProxies.Add(IPAddress.Parse("89.111.170.109"));
});

app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});
```

However, for some reason, when trying to navigate to the IP address of the cloud server, the error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` is displayed. What could be the problem?

I tried to change the server name and ports in default nginx file, tried to set `HttpsRedirection()` in Program.cs, but nothing works for me.

Comment: Have you used the `sudo ufw allow port_num/tcp` command to allow the  specific port?

Comment: @JasonPan Could you please tell me which port should be specified? I’m just new to Ubuntu, and I do everything according to the tutorial, but this command is not there

Comment: You can try to allow 80 and 5000 port for testing.

Comment: @JasonPan I wrote `sudo ufw allow 80/tcp` and `sudo ufw allow 5000/tcp` but unfortunately that didn't help me

Comment: Please use `sudo systemctl status AspNetServer.service` command to check your web app is runnning or not ?

Comment: And I also need to check your Program.cs file, please don't forget to hide your sensitive information.